# Node.js change url base with prefix

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js app with express and jade templates.
Just now I've running like any-host:8000 but I need to change to any-host:8000/web/
but this causes change all href and location css,img,js...

Any idea to do something to achieve transparently

I've tried with:

```
app.namespace('/admin', function(){...}
```

but then I need change the href of all the html links in the app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use('/urlbase', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

(assuming your app is located in `myapp/`).

Comment: But with this I need change all the href in html links